# Display LaTeX Equations in-line with terminal

Tags: python, latex, terminal, ipython

I'm writing a python library to solve various physics equations, and would like to add a method to each equation to display the equation formatted in LaTeX.  I thought about using a LaTeX to PNG converter, and then somehow displaying the image in-line with the terminal, which led me to trying to figure out displaying images in the terminal, to no avail.  If it makes things simpler, I mainly use IPython, and wouldn't mind if it only worked in that.

If there really is no way to display images in-line, then I could always just display them in a window, but that wouldn't be nearly as clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This excellent [ipython talk](http://pyvideo.org/video/640/ipython-python-at-your-fingertips) from PyCon 2012 has a demonstration of converting equations (algebraic) to their graphical representations and displaying them inline and could possibly help you figure out how to do the same for your physics equations.

Comment: See also the tutorial from the same conference http://pyvideo.org/video/605/ipython-in-depth-high-productivity-interactive-a

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a terminal, but the [ipython notebook](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html) interface is capable of doing this already.

One of the PyCon2012 sprints was on writing notebook converters to and from a number of text formats, so if you can't conveniently do what you're trying to do yet, expect it soon.