# How to display math-text in Kivy Python?

Tags: python, math, fonts, kivy

I would like to ask on how to display a math-text in a `kivy` app..? For example : How to do the same thing as `$ \frac{1}{2} $` or `$ 2^{3} $` does in LaTeX (omitting the font type, as long as it is *math-readable*).

I know that in `matplotlib.pyplot` module, I can use string : `r'$ \frac{1}{2} $'` or `r'$ 2^{3} $'` to produce a math-text. But this does not produce the desired result in `kivy` :

`Label(text = r'$\frac{1}{2}$' )` will reproduce **$\frac{1}{2}$**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please Take a look at the [sympy module](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiN2ZCb65PXAhUKPxoKHS4vDCgQFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sympy.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw2i29LeGz2UzoBRWrw6IIp0), then in your label you must use a `font_name` that can display math-text

but If you want to use Latex formula then you have to find a font_name that can display those formula like you want

**Update**: Otherwise you can generate your Latex in a **png** then integrate it in your kivy app

Comment: Thanks. I have just tried the `sympy` module. I have used one of the syntax and converted it to string, to put it on the `Label`, but this also does not work. What `font_name` that can display math-text..? I tried several names..only `Arial` that does not produce an Error.

Comment: try the asana-math  you can get it here  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3XGn7xdfoSNNDRXZE50dWtXaXM

Comment: Thanks again. I have registered it using `LabelBase.register`. But I don't think this has something to do with `sympy`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried 2 ways to display mathematical notation on Kivy Label:
(Each of way includes SymPy or Matplotlib)

1- Use SymPy printing module

```
from sympy import *
...
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
```

Do not forget this piece display mathematical notation but you have to use needed font name for Kivy label to display mathematical notation perfectly. I know one, it's "dejavusans mono" yeah this is monospace font.

2- Use Matplotlib. turn to png then display the png on Kivy Image
here is good example [display math symbols with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110709/creating-images-of-mathematical-expressions-from-tex-using-matplotlib)

*(here is sample code):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

from sympy import *
x,y,z = symbols('x y z')
init_printing(use_unicode=True)

kiv=Builder.load_string("""
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            id:lbl1
            text:'math-equation'
            markup:True
            #font_name:'dejavusansmono.ttf' ----here your monospace font
        Label:
            id:lbl2
            text:'math-equation'
            markup:True
            #font_name:'dejavusansmono.ttf'  ----here your monospace font
            
        Button:
            id:btn
            text:'Display'
            on_press:root.display()       
""")

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    def display(self):
        expression=Derivative(sqrt(x+2)*cos(x+2), x)
        answer=expression.doit()
        good_symbols1=pretty(expression)
        good_symbols2=pretty(answer)

        self.ids.lbl1.text=good_symbols1
        self.ids.lbl2.text=good_symbols2
        
class Example(App):

    def build(self):
        scr=MainScreen()
        return scr

Example().run()
```

[Out]: [image]