# How to display math formulas in kivy app?

Tags: python, math, kivy, latex

I am coding sth. like a quiz App for my math students in kivy and want to publish that as a mobile application for Android and iOS.

Now I am trying to show math formulas in a label, but I don't know how to do that.

Is there anything like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex for kivy? I can't imagine, that this just exists for Flutter even though kivy is older than Flutter.

I read some questions here like [How to display math-text in Kivy Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988603/how-to-display-math-text-in-kivy-python) but I don't want to export my equation to a .png file

Although the few posts here at stack overflow are at least 4 years old, so I hope, that nowadays is a solution for this problem :)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988603/how-to-display-math-text-in-kivy-python/76410103#76410103

Answer (score 1):

Kivy doesn't have particularly good equation display functionality. You'll need to find a renderer that can do it and integrate that into kivy (but I don't know if there are any good options), or pregenerate images, or manually hack things together with label positioning and unicode characters if what you're doing is simple enough.

> Is there anything like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex for kivy? I can't imagine, that this just exists for Flutter even though kivy is older than Flutter.

Unfortunately age isn't everything, Kivy is supported by a small group of volunteers while Flutter has enormous commercial support.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Unicode is just helping with very basic formulas :( I wanted to avoid generating images, so I have to find a renderer for that. If anybody knows a way, pls feel free to tell me.

Comment: And yeah, sad, that Kivy isn't having commercial support like Flutter, I see a big potential in Kivy!